# SAS writing file using variables line with line holding and loop

Tags: sas

I am trying to write a file using some variables stored in an external file. I have a trouble using line holder(@@ with put statement) and loop. I like to put variables in some places in the file but the resut file I got repeats by each line of those variables. I just want those variables to be placed at one time as a chunk.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
data _null_;
 set merged;
 file 'c:outfile.txt';
 put @1 "A" @4 &totaln.;
 do i=1 to &totaln;  
  put @1 i @4 "L3 2 DW 1.7" @17 a @28 b @40 c @@;
 end;   
 put;
 put @1 "OL" @4 &totaln.;
 do j=1 to &totaln.;
  put @1 j put @4 "L3 2 DW 1.7" put @17 av @28 bv @40 cv @@;
 end;
 put;
 put    @1 "CI &totaln. AO";
 put    @1 "OP";
 put    @1 "KO" @4 "SL";
run;
```

&totaln. is the total number of count in the merged file that i made. 'Merged' contains a, b, c, av, ab, ac variables ( their rows are about 19 of them). So i want 19 rows of a,b,c variables below NE totaln line. And then the same thing for av, bv, cv below OL totaln line then the three lines of CI OP and Ko lines at the end of the outfile.

merged:

A   B         C         av               bv                  ac          cnt
0.0268  676.9155    0.0347  0.9620294118    -2.131070959    0.031533299 1
0.0215  704.6740    0.2240  0.7738647059    -1.185638164    0.3506849035    2
0.0430  736.3752    0.2053  1.5611941176    -0.442240668    0.2434476134    3
0.0223  727.6945    0.1752  0.8075882353    -0.833957317    0.1725987826    4
0.0220  715.3714    0.1187  0.7434058824    -0.991003252    0.120438949 5
0.0287  754.1052    0.1824  0.8567470588    0.126161198 0.1685302022    6

outfille look:
NE   6
1 L3 2 DW 1.7  0.0268   676.9155    0.0347
2 L3 2 DW 1.7  0.0215   704.6740    0.2240
3 L3 2 DW 1.7  0.0430   736.3752    0.2053
4 L3 2 DW 1.7  0.0223   727.6945    0.1752
5 L3 2 DW 1.7  0.0220   715.3714    0.1187
6 L3 2 DW 1.7  0.0287   754.1052    0.1824
OL   6
1 L3 2 DW 1.7 0.9620294118  -2.131070959    0.031533299
2 L3 2 DW 1.7 0.7738647059  -1.185638164    0.3506849035
3 L3 2 DW 1.7 1.5611941176  -0.442240668    0.2434476134
4 L3 2 DW 1.7 0.8075882353  -0.833957317    0.1725987826
5 L3 2 DW 1.7 0.7434058824  -0.991003252    0.120438949
6 L3 2 DW 1.7 0.8567470588  0.126161198 0.1685302022
CI 6 AO
OP
KO SL

Comment: You need to post the data from MERGED. Also, each PUT statement needs a semi-colon...in your DO-END you have several put statements on the same line. I doubt anyone can solve this without seeing some sample successful output. Post the input data and how you want it to look.

Answer (score 1):

In order to split the data set down the middle (essentially) and put the left 3 variables above the right 3 variables in the output file...you need to 2 data steps. I split the variables into 2 data sets. Once the output file is created with the 1st 3 variables, it can be written to again using the MOD option on the FILE statement. You probably need to adjust some of your Put @ locations to make the variables align into columns. Also, in this example it appears that "L3 2 DW 1.7" is a constant, put that in a macro variable so that it only needs to be changed in one location.

Try this:

```
proc sql;
select count(*) into:totaln
from merged;
quit;

data merged1(keep=cnt a b c) merged2(keep=cnt av bv ac);
 input A B C av bv ac cnt;
 datalines;
 0.0268 676.9155 0.0347 0.9620294118 -2.131070959 0.031533299 1
 0.0215 704.6740 0.2240 0.7738647059 -1.185638164 0.3506849035 2
 0.0430 736.3752 0.2053 1.5611941176 -0.442240668 0.2434476134 3
 0.0223 727.6945 0.1752 0.8075882353 -0.833957317 0.1725987826 4
 0.0220 715.3714 0.1187 0.7434058824 -0.991003252 0.120438949 5
 0.0287 754.1052 0.1824 0.8567470588 0.126161198 0.1685302022 6 
 ;
run;

data _null_;
 set merged1;
 file "C:\outfile.txt";
 if _n_=1 then put @1 "NE" @4 "&totaln";
 put @1 cnt @4 "L3 2 DW 1.7" @17 a @28 b @40 c;
run;

data _null_;
 set merged2 end=last;
 file "C:\outfile.txt" mod;
 if _n_=1 then put @1 "OL" @4 "&totaln";
 put @1 cnt put @4 "L3 2 DW 1.7" put @17 av @28 bv @40 ac;
 if last then do;
  put    @1 "CI &totaln. AO";
  put    @1 "OP";
  put    @1 "KO" @4 "SL";
 end;
run;
```

Comment: Thnaks you billion CarolinaJay! it worked beautifully. And then in addition to yours, I just made totaln as a macro variable using proc sql in "merged" instead of using let  macro statement. thank you so much !!

Comment: but now it is not working using  macro variable totaln. doe sit have to be with only %let statment to use total n count?

Comment: No, you can certainly create your macro variable using SQL. Post your SQL code in your question.

Comment: proc sql;   select count(*)   into:totaln   from merged;   quit;  But it gives the totaln number but not in the right column.

Comment: the totaln goes way out  than the designated column

Comment: oh ok that was the problem. i wil lthen use trim to get rid of  blanks. that i think I can dig around more. thank you for your expertise!